# Implement R model in Python

Tags: python, r, gam

How can I implement a GAM model developed in R (using `mgcv`) in Python using `statsmodels` library. The model in R is:

```
gam_model<- gam(y ~  var1 + var2 + var1:var2 +  s(var1, bs="re", by = var2), data = df, family = nb, weights = var2))
```

By implementing it I mean I want to replicate the model to do both the training and predictions in Python.

Comment: This is a built-in module: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/gam.html

Comment: Hey @Fourier! I know it, but I don't know how to pass from one model to another using it... Could you help me out?

Comment: Do you want to 1): call R function from Python that can predict the GAM model, or 2). Simply using "run" this GAM model purely in Python?

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu I'm looking for the second option

Comment: AFAIR, the `by` option for interactions of splines with categorical variables is not yet supported by statsmodels.